# Moment of inertia of apollo 11 lunar module

Tags: apollo-program, lunar-landing, physics

I'm currently modeling the lunar landing in 2D.

When I set up the momentum balance: $\ddot{\theta} = \frac{dF_l}{J}$ where $d$ is the distance between the sidethruster and the center of mass. $F_l$ is the force from the side thruster and $J$ is the moment of inertia.

I don't really have a background in physics, and was wondering what a decent value for $J$ could be. At the moment it's at 100 000 and the distance is 4. But I'd like to be able to explain why I chose these values. 
Any input would be enormously helpful

Comment: There is a huge command / lunar module mass properties document posted here: https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/SNA-8-D-027III-Rev2-CsmLmSpacecraftOperationalDataBook-Volume3-MassProperties.pdf  I have not looked through it to see if it answers your question so posting as a comment.